# Random selection in Combobox?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to know how could do to make a combobox to display a different selection each time you load the page, not create them, if not to show the options that exist, each time you load the page shows a different selection....like randomize the default selected option...thank's in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you want to have the dropdown values the same every time, but the selected value should be different on every reload?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
var select = document.getElementById('foo');
var items = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);

select.selectedIndex = index;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lakario/dHLax/