# Random selection 1, 3, 5 in combobox?

Tags: javascript, html, random

Firt of all, I'm very sorry if I have some mistakes in English.

```
<select id="listserver">
    <option value="http://radio.xx.net/live/128">Vietel - 128 kbps</option>
    <option value="http://radio.xx.net/live/64">Vietel - 64 kbps</option>
    <option value="http://123.30.xx.xx:8000/live/128">VNPT - 128 kbps</option>
    <option value="http://123.30.xx.xx:8000/live/64">VNPT - 64 kbps</option>
    <option value="http://210.245.xx.xx:8000/live/128">FPT - 128 kbps</option>
    <option value="http://210.245.xx.xx:8000/live/64">FPT - 64 kbps</option>
</select>
```

I have a code to select server to listen to radio like this. Now I want have a bandwidth balance with my 3 server, and 128 kbps quality by default.

I have read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889207/random-selection-in-combobox), and it can help me do this.

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep an array of the default items and only pick those.  In this case the 128 kbps items are found at index 0, 2, and 4.

```
var defaultItems = [0,2,4]
var select = document.getElementById('listserver');
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * defaultItems.length);

select.selectedIndex = defaultItems[index];
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dHLax/54/)

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to each option tag:

```
<select id="listserver">
    <option id="1" value="http://radio.xx.net/live/128">Vietel - 128 kbps</option>
    <option id="2" value="http://radio.xx.net/live/64">Vietel - 64 kbps</option>
    <option id="3" value="http://123.30.xx.xx:8000/live/128">VNPT - 128 kbps</option>
    <option id="4" value="http://123.30.xx.xx:8000/live/64">VNPT - 64 kbps</option>
    <option id="5" value="http://210.245.xx.xx:8000/live/128">FPT - 128 kbps</option>
    <option id="6" value="http://210.245.xx.xx:8000/live/64">FPT - 64 kbps</option>
</select>
```

Then you can assign selected='selected' or simply selected to the option you want selected. You can use Javascript and JQuery to generate a random number between 1 and 3:

```
<script>
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
```

and finally add the selected attribute to the randomly selected option:

```
    if(num == 1){
        $('#1').attr('selected', 'selected');
    }elseif(num == 2){
    etc....

</script>
```

Hope this is clear enough :)